# separate key animations on HTML elements one after the other

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I was wondering is there away in css to use the same key animations on elements that have a delay. For example I have a list of elements that have the same class and for each element it uses key animations but there is delay for each element for 1 second each so they don't play at the same time but one after the other. If you can do this in css could someone show me how to do this in jsFiddle please and leave a message, thanks from KDM

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite simply in CSS by just calling the animation with a different delay

```
* { animation: $name $duration $timing-function; } // all elements you want get animation called
.element { animation-delay: 100ms; } // set the delay here
.other-element { animation-delay: 200ms; } // set it again for different delays
```

If you can't specify a different class for each element you want to have a different delay, than just use nth-child selctors.

```
nth-child(odd) { animation-delay: 100ms; }
nth-child(even) { animation-delay: 200ms; }
```

you can also do this in SASS / Less using a mixin I wrote to call animations with different properties.

```
@mixin animation($name, $duration: 1000ms, $iterations: infinite, $timing-function: ease, $delay: 0ms) {
  -webkit-animation: $name $duration $iterations $timing-function $delay;
  -moz-animation: $name $duration $iterations $timing-function $delay;
  -o-animation: $name $duration $iterations $timing-function $delay;
  animation: $name $duration $iterations $timing-function $delay;
}
```

The $name must be specified, which is referring to the animation keyframes you want to run. All other properties have default values in case they are not specified. In your case, just use that mixin on any elements you want but give each one a different delay value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to animate your elements in sequence, you can use something like this:

```
@mixin sequenceAnimate($animationName, $elements: 1, $animationDuration: 1s, $animationDelay: 1s)    
  @for $i from 1 through $elements
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i})
      -webkit-animation-name: $animationName
      -webkit-animation-duration: $animationDuration
      -webkit-animation-delay: $animationDelay * $i
```

**[Live demo here!](http://codepen.io/myajouri/pen/iuHLE)**